# iOS Swift Chart : Bar chart background colour

Tags: ios, swift, xcode, charts, bar-chart

I create a bar chart that works completely fine. How can I add the bar chart capsule background color? Not want the entire chart background color but I want to need a background color for each bar so it will look like fill and unfill like effet to the bar chat.

```
    var BAR_WIDTH_CONSTANT: CGFloat = 3
    var BAR_DISTANCE: CGFloat = 14
    var BAR_MAX_HEIGHT: CGFloat = 50
    let MAX_VALUE: CGFloat = 60
    let MIN_VALUE: CGFloat = 0
    var unitsSold = [20.0, 4.0, 6.0, 3.0, 12.0, 16.0, 4.0]
    var months = ["Mon", "Tue", "Wed", "Thu", "Fri", "Sat", "Sun"]
    var graphType = 1
    var maxValue = 30.0

   func setChart(arrX:[String]) {
        let customFormater = BarChartFormatter()
        customFormater.months = self.months
        
        viewChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = customFormater
        self.viewChart.xAxis.labelPosition = XAxis.LabelPosition.bottom
        self.viewChart.setVisibleXRangeMaximum(Double(arrX.count))
        self.viewChart.fitScreen()
        
        var dataEntries = [BarChartDataEntry]()
        
        for i in 0..<months.count {
            let dataEntry = BarChartDataEntry(x: Double(i), y: Double(unitsSold[i]), data: months as AnyObject?)
            dataEntries.append(dataEntry)
        }
        
        let chartDataSet = BarChartDataSet(entries: dataEntries, label: "")
        chartDataSet.valueTextColor = .clear
        
        chartDataSet.valueFont = themeFont(size: 9, fontname: .Poppins_Black)
        
        
        chartDataSet.colors = [.appThemeColor, UIColor(named: "DarkGreen")!]
        
        //Remove 0 value from graphs
        let noZeroFormatter = NumberFormatter()
        noZeroFormatter.zeroSymbol = ""
        chartDataSet.valueFormatter = DefaultValueFormatter(formatter: noZeroFormatter)
        
        chartDataSet.barShadowColor = .clear
        let chartData = BarChartData(dataSet: chartDataSet)
        
        chartData.barWidth = 0.6
        
//        if graphType == 1 || graphType == 3  {
//            chartData.barWidth = 0.4
//        }
        
        viewChart.data = chartData
        viewChart.animate(xAxisDuration: 1, yAxisDuration: 1, easingOption: .linear)
    }

func setupChart() {
    viewChart.delegate = self
    viewChart.chartDescription.enabled = false
    viewChart.dragEnabled = true
    viewChart.doubleTapToZoomEnabled = false
    viewChart.pinchZoomEnabled = false
    viewChart.xAxis.valueFormatter = self
    viewChart.legend.enabled = false
    viewChart.setScaleEnabled(false)
    viewChart.isUserInteractionEnabled = false
    
    let leftAxisFormatter = NumberFormatter()
    leftAxisFormatter.maximumFractionDigits = 0
    
    let xAxis = viewChart.xAxis
    xAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = true
    xAxis.labelPosition = .topInside
    xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 0
    xAxis.labelFont = themeFont(size: 12, fontname: .Poppins_Light)
    xAxis.labelTextColor = .darkGray
    
    xAxis.granularity = 1
    
    xAxis.axisLineWidth = 0
    xAxis.labelCount = 12
    xAxis.granularityEnabled = true
    xAxis.valueFormatter = self
    xAxis.labelRotationAngle = 0
    xAxis.gridColor = .clear

    let yAxis = viewChart.leftAxis
    yAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    yAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    yAxis.axisMaximum = Double(maxValue)
    yAxis.axisLineWidth = 0
    yAxis.labelTextColor = .clear
    yAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    yAxis.labelPosition = .outsideChart
  
    let dAxis = viewChart.rightAxis
    dAxis.drawGridLinesEnabled = false
    dAxis.axisMinimum = 0
    dAxis.axisLineWidth = 0
    dAxis.labelTextColor = .clear
    dAxis.drawLabelsEnabled = true
    dAxis.labelPosition = .outsideChart
}
```

This is what I'm looking for.
[image]

This is what I have done yet.

[image]

Comment: Without being able to see the code that you are using to create your chart it is not really going to be possible to advise you on how you can do what you want. You should update your question with the minimum code required to reproduce your issue so that those who are inclined to help you are able to.

Comment: I add code. Both Function is called in `ViewDidLoad`

Comment: Look up corner radius, at least that would be the tag if this were SwiftUI. Wrote half a dozen articles on this subject under swiftUI too that you will find here https://medium.com/@marklucking

Comment: The code is in swift not in SwiftUI

Comment: What are you using to draw the graph because from the code you have posted you have not included it? If it is an external package such as Charts then you will have to look at their documentation to see if it is possible, if it isn’t in the documentation you will probably need to subclass their code and edit it to make your own chart. That could be a lot of work, and perhaps out of scope for a SO answer

Answer (score 0):

if you are drwaing your BarChart using Charts, then to apply corner radius you should have to change the internal code of the Charts Framework.

You can do it as:
Search (Shift+Command+O) for the BarChartRenderer.swift (Shift+Command+O) file and replace the (every)line

```
context.fill(barRect)
```

with the code below

```
let bezierPath = UIBezierPath(roundedRect: barRect, cornerRadius: 3.0)
context.addPath(bezierPath.cgPath)
context.drawPath(using: .fill)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).